# Return multiple variables from logical statements

Tags: string, lua

This is my code to explode a string into a list of each individual character without using tables:

```
function explode(s)
    if#s==1 then
        return s
    end
    return s:sub(1,1),explode(s:sub(2))
end
```

where #s==#({explode(s)})
In an attempt to make this code shorter, I wanted to do this:

```
function explode(s)
    return#s>1 and(s:sub(1,1),explode(s:sub(2)))or s
end
```

but that won't work because '[condition] a and [result value] b or [alternative] c' doesn't call for having multiple results or alternatives. Is there some other way to return the same result using only one statement?

Comment: "*Is there some other way to return the same result using only one statement?*" Is there some reason you *need* to?

Comment: for the sake of writing the shortest possible function to return a list of every individual character in a string without using tables.

Comment: Recursive calls will lead to Stack Overflow

Comment: I ran it in a 10000-length string and it worked fine.

Comment: `if s~='' then return s:sub(1,1),explode(s:sub(2)) end`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Nice pun! :D

Answer (score 6):

Here is another idea:

```
function explode(s)
    return s:match(("(.)"):rep(s:len()))
end
```

Note that this is not very efficient.

Comment: Inefficient, yes, but really clever trick given the requirements (+1)!

Comment: This won't work if the length of the string is more than 32 characters.

Answer (score 1):

On one line you can do:

```
function explode(s)
  return unpack(#s > 1 and {s:sub(1,1), explode( s:sub(2) )} or {s})
end
```

Warning, this is *not* efficient.

Comment: Well, this solution *do use* tables, so it doesn't match the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is another version that uses tail recursion optimization, so it is more efficient:

```
function explode_helper( s, pos, ... )
    if pos <= 0 then return ... end
    return explode_helper( s, pos - 1, s:sub( pos, pos ), ... )
end

function explode( s )
    local n = #s
    return explode_helper( s, n - 1, s:sub( n ) )
end

print( explode "Hello World" )
```

The limit for this method is the maximum number of arguments a Lua vararg (`...`) can handle. IIRC for Lua 5.1 was about 8000. Lua 5.2 increased that number.

Comment: Mmmh, now I see in a comment that the OP also wants *"the shortest possible function"*, so my solution doesn't match this criteria. Oh, well ...